# JSON string manipulation using regular expression

Tags: java, json, regex

Hi I have been trying to get the regex to replace dot (.) in the JSON string key names. I don't want to use JSONObject to convert the string to JSON.

So for the JSON string like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "property": "0",
        "property_value": "0",
        "property": "0",
        "pro.per.ty": "0",
        "pr.op.er.ty": "0.0",
        "property": "0.0",
        "proper_ty": "0.0",
        "group": "oneGroup",
        "newprop": "0",
        "total": {
            "0": "0",
            "99": "0",
            "100": "0",
            "25": "0",
            "90": "0",
            "50": "0",
            "95": "0",
            "99.5": "0",
            "75": "0"
        },
        "requests": "0"
    }
}
```

I want the final string to be

```
{
    "data": {
        "property": "0",
        "property_value": "0",
        "property": "0",
        "pro_per_ty": "0",
        "pr_op_er_ty": "0.0",
        "property": "0.0",
        "proper_ty": "0.0",
        "group": "oneGroup",
        "newprop": "0",
        "total": {
            "0": "0",
            "99": "0",
            "100": "0",
            "25": "0",
            "90": "0",
            "50": "0",
            "95": "0",
            "99_5": "0",
            "75": "0"
        },
        "requests": "0"
    }
}
```

The solution needs to be highly performant with sub 10msec time.

I am able to capture the keys with (.) using the expression `"(\w*\.\w*)+\":` but I am unable to get the subgroups correctly to perform the replacement.

Comment: So you don't just want to replace _all_ instances of dots with underscores, but only those in keys?

Comment: *I don't want to use JSONObject to convert the string to JSON.* Why?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with the following but not sure if this can be bettered by reducing the number of `String` objects that are created

```
String cleanse(final String jsonString){
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?:\\w*\\.\\w*)+)\"\\s*?:");
String str = jsonString;
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()) {
str = str.replace(matcher.group(1),matcher.group(1).replaceAll("\\.","_"));
}
return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider below non-regex based approach :

```
public static String cleanse( String str )
{
    String updated = Arrays.stream( str.split( "," ) ).map( value -> {
        if ( !value.contains( ":" ) )
        {
            return value;
        }
        String[] pair = value.split( ":" );
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        while ( i < pair.length - 1 )
        {
            sb.append( pair[i] ).append( ":" );
            i++;
        }
        return sb.toString().replace( '.', '_' ) + pair[i];
    } ).collect( Collectors.joining( "," ) );

    return updated;
}
```

Since it is not using Pattern matching so it should be performant.

Comment: Thanks @Mahendra for your solution. Trying it on the actual data string (~1.8kb) is yielding average timings of 50+ ms. The pattern matching is consistently yielding ~5 ms.